# Add Wp_editor to textarea in array

Tags: php, wordpress

i was trying to enable the wp_editor on a fieldset i have for a plugin, i wonder if you could take a look:

```
function custom_metaboxes( $meta_boxes ) {
    $prefix = '_pre_'; // Prefix for all fields


    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'id' => 'test_metabox',
        'title' => __('Text area', 'montreal'),
        'pages' => array('post', 'portfolio'), // post type
        'context' => 'normal',
        'priority' => 'high',
        'show_names' => true, // Show field names on the left
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'name' => __('test 1', 'test'),
                'desc' => __('desc', 'test'),
                'id' => $prefix . 'g1',
                'type' => 'textarea',
                'save_id' => false, 
             attachments with array( 'attachment' )
            ),

        ),
    );
```

I tried implementing this code but it crashes:

```
<?php wp_editor( $content, $prefix . 'g1', $settings = array() ); ?>
```

When it crashes i mean a text editor shows up in every page of the site of only apearing on the textarea with the id = ($prefix . 'g1').

I this the right way to enable the editor on that text area?

Comment: Are you asking about the `,,` syntax error?

Comment: oh no, sorry fixed it @mario

Comment: Then explain what actually happens. "It crashes" is not a useful description.

Comment: see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/49906/69071) to a similar question.